# Would it be legal to use a brand's name (e,g, Samsung, macOS) in my personal email address?

Tags: intellectual-property, trademark, is-x-legal

I have my main email as "mer************windows14@gmail.com" *(censored for safety)*

Now in the email, it has "Windows" and I'm worried that Microsoft will come for me and say"**HEY!**, you cant use Microsoft's trademarked services in your email address".

Is it okay or should I change my email?

(I did see the question [Use of trademark in personal email alias](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/32980/use-of-trademark-in-personal-email-alias) but i didn't really understand much of it, maybe my situation is different since I'm not a part of Microsoft or it affiliates)

Comment: Are you using the e-mail handle in a manner that suggests some sort of affiliation with Windows? "OfficialWindowsCustomerService@gmail.com" is probably going to be a lot different from "LookingOutWindowsAtTheSky@gmail.com."

Comment: @bdb484 no, this is just my personal email, the email fully is mervinpaismakeswindows14@gmail.com, the windows part was because i made other versions of windows on scratch (scratch.mit.edu) so i made this email for fun, now its my main email..

Comment: basically i was know for "making windows ripoff versions" at school so i made this email for fun email anyone were wanting to chat with me

Comment: I guess its OK as it got thru the filters as I tried to make a Gmail account with 'admin' but it got rejected by the AI

Comment: "censored for safety" then using it as your username and posting it in the comments within a few minutes doesn't seem to be right...

Comment: @RonBeyer, spambots aren't smart enough to use the username to decensor the email address into something usable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not categorically illegal, there is a risk that using a trademark in an email name is something that is being done with a purpose to defraud people into thinking that you are affiliated with that company (and indeed, such emails are frequently used for that purpose as are misleading domain names).

So, while it isn't outright forbidden, it is generally unwise.

Comment: ok, so if i am saying to people "Hey! im a part of *brand Name*", unless i am actually as a part of *brand Name*, then i would be doing something illegal, else if i just used a name just for other then representing *brand Name* then im ok, got it :)